# How I can use a range between 0-20 on this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, drupal-7

How I can use a range between 0-20 on this sql query?

```
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid  
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM t1
          RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
          limit 0, 20';
  $result = db_query($sql);//->fetchField();
```

Comment: `where foo BETWEEN 0 AND 20` in the middle?  We could keep guessing, but really this question is hopelessly unclear.  Clarify what you want!

Comment: I want, every time this lines runs, to take different rows every time..

Comment: That makes even less sense.  Please be *specific*.  Sample data may help to exemplify your problem.

Comment: i want when these lines run take 20 rows from these tables then when these lines reruns take some other 20 rows.. I cannot be more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass LIMIT into your query. and your limit would be variable every time like

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid  
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM t1
          RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid) AS A LIMIT'.$start.','.$end
```

Comment: the start and end what will be?

Comment: and really i want something like that you are so amazing thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

please please sanatize your query as this is very easy to SQL inject. For drupal it should be:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1
      LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid  
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM t1
      RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid) AS A LIMIT :min, :max',
      array('min' => $min, 'max' => $max));
```

There are better Drupal ways to write this but this is ok as long as you pass the variables as arguments.